# AMP как правильно писать input type="tel"

Tags: html5, валидация, amp

Подскажите, есть ли для amp страниц какой-то метод для правильного написания (возможно с валидацией) для поля input type="tel" при отправке формы? А то что-то не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Пример от W3 школы](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_tel.asp)**:

```
Telephone: <input type="tel" name="usrtel">
```

**[Пример от Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)**:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact information</legend>

    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
           placeholder="123-456-7890"
           pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
           required />
    <span class="validity"></span>

</fieldset>
```